# About updating C++ header files

Tags: c++, compilation, header, g++

This question is about something that after more than a year with C++ I can't solve or find any solution about it.

I got used to using separate files for headers and code in C, but I have a problem with it on C++: whenever I edit a header file and try to compile the code that uses it again, the compiler doesn't notice the change on the header.

What I do to solve this is "compiling" the header (.hpp) alone. Sometimes I just add it to the list of source files for g++ along with the rest of the code, but what happens then is that I have to execute the command twice (the first time it gives me errors, but not the second time). It also warns me that I'm using the "pragma once" option in a main file.

I know this is very wrong, so I've searched for a correct way to do this, without success. I have noticed that g++ generates ".gch" files but I don't really know what's their purpose, although they may be related.

I suspect that the problem is caused because of the code in the ".hpp". I know (I think) that the good way to do it is to define prototypes only inside the header and writing the body of the methods in a separate file, but sometimes (specially when using templates) this generates even more problems.

Comment: You are indeed building your program in all manner of wrongness. We cannot say anything about your problem without reproduction steps, though. The compiler can't "not notice" the changes because a source file, along with anything it `#include`s is _always_ fully compiled when you, um, compile it. It's more likely that you have not configured your build system properly to resolve source→header dependencies. If you're using GNU Make, [this documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html) will help you; in the meantime, not sure we can help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't figure out how to PM another user so I'm doing a bad thing and putting a message for you here. I just wanted you to know that the Alicia Silverstone quote in your profile made my week. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .gch is a precompiled header and it is created if you explicitly compile a header file.
The compiler will then use that file instead of the actual header (the compiler does not care about modification timestamps).

Do `rm *.gch` and leave all headers out of the compilation command forever.

(And don't put template implementations in .cpp files.)